# continuing a math container on next page with Typst

Tags: typst

I have a numbered equation in Typst that is becoming a bit long and I want to break it in 2 so it continues on the next page, but the numbering doesnt split.

Tried using `#pagebreak`, but that's not possible inside a container. Is there a way to split the container without breaking numbering or properly have it just split over 2 pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when `#pagebreak()` fails because of it being in a container, `#colbreak()` can work. Unfortunately not here though, I'd recommend just resetting the equation counter manually and splitting up the equations with: `#counter(math.equation).update(0)` for example.